# UIWindow rounded corners throughout application

Tags: ios, cocoa, window, rounded-corners, mask

I want to have small rounded corners around the edges of my app (across the whole app) so I figured the best place to do this was on the layer of the main `UIWindow` created in the `AppDelegate` class. Here's my code...

```
[self.window.layer setCornerRadius:30.0f];
[self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

This does round the corners at the bottom of my window, and slightly at the top. However the window is the full size of the screen (not the screen minus status bar) so I end up with something like this.. http://tfld.me/image/441U0j3w3X3N

I don't really want to add the cornerRadius/masksToBounds option on every layer on all nav controllers/views in my app.. or have a background image (as thats not very future proof).

I have also tried setting these options on the windows rootViewController with no luck - http://tfld.me/image/0c1m2w36402K

Any suggestions much appreciated :)

Comment: The Status Bar is itself a window and its level is above the normal window. In order have rounded corners across the status bar you need to get the status bar window. Unfortunately the method to get the status bar window is not there.  You access through the private property.  UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarWindow];
    [window.layer setCornerRadius:20.0f];
    [window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

Comment: Sorry I don't mean I want to round the status bar, I want to round *my application* below the status bar.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the navigation bar to be curved you can used appropriate image. If not then the below code should work as per your need:

```
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] init] autorelease];
    //shift the window frame by 20 px so that it goes below status bar
    CGRect sampleRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    sampleRect.origin.y += 20.0;
    sampleRect.size.height -= 20.0;
    self.window.frame = sampleRect;

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    vc.view.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    UINavigationController *mRootController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
    CGRect navFrame = mRootController.view.frame;
    navFrame.origin.y -= 20.0; //Shift the navigation frame up by 20 px
    mRootController.view.frame = navFrame;

    [self.window addSubview:mRootController.view];
    [self.window.layer setCornerRadius:20.0f];
    [self.window.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: +1 Works nice if we do `[self.window addSubview:mRootController.view];` but if we set the `mRootController` as rootViewControllerof the `self.window` then the solution is not working as per the expectation.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4:

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        window.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        window.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that I have used a small png file which contains 1/4 of a transparent circle (whose radius will be the new radius of the window) and black towards the corner (a designer provided me the image, you may have to do it yourself). I have created 4 `imageView` s using this png, rotated them accordingly and added them as subviews to `navigationController`.

Put the following method into your `appDelegate` and invoke it inside `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`: method after initializing the `navigationController`.

```
-(void) insertCornerRadiiOnNavigationController : (UINavigationController *) navController{

CGFloat cornerRadius = 7;

UIImageView *corner1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];
UIImageView *corner2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([_window bounds].size.width - cornerRadius, 20, cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];
UIImageView *corner3 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [_window bounds].size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];
UIImageView *corner4 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([_window bounds].size.width - cornerRadius, [_window bounds].size.height - cornerRadius, cornerRadius, cornerRadius)];

corner2.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (M_PI_2);
corner3.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (3 * M_PI_2);
corner4.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation (M_PI);

[corner1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner.png"]];
[corner2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner.png"]];
[corner3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner.png"]];
[corner4 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"corner.png"]];

[navController.navigationBar addSubview:corner1];
[navController.navigationBar addSubview:corner2];
[navController.view addSubview:corner3];
[navController.view addSubview:corner4];

[corner1 release];
[corner2 release];
[corner3 release];
[corner4 release];
}
```

For some reason I could not add them to `UIWindow` directly, the `imageViews` did not appear.